# How can I trigger on onItemClick of a list item from a button?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a custom list adapter that I see when I press an item in the list I can see in the debugger that I end up in the `onItemClick` of another class.
I can't find how the adapter and the other class are connected i.e. how we end up calling the `onItemClick` of the other class. I can't find any `setOnitemClickListener` or something similar.
Anyway my problem is:
I have a button inside the list view item. I want when pressing the button to trigger an `onItemClick` with the same parameters as if the list item was pressed.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can call performItemClick() method on litsview

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
final View returnView;
if (convertView == null) {
  returnView = new View(parent.getContext());// initial your view here
} else {
  returnView = convertView;
}
View btn = returnView.findViewById(android.R.id.button1);// find your button
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    AbsListView absList = (AbsListView) parent;
    absList.performItemClick(returnView, position, getItemId(position));
  }
});
return returnView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi just add this line to your code

```
myList.setItemsCanFocus(true);
```